# Javascript/html file won't open properly in browser??? Browser just keeps loading infinitely (tried on safari and chrome)

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to run both the code on my pc and laptop but same issue, and laptop overheats while pc just gets stuck after running the code.

This is the code:

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Okay</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello</p>


    <script src="jslevelone.js"> </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript code: (filename : jslevelone.js)

```
var num = 1
while (num < 26) {
  if (num % 2 !== 0) {
    console.log("The odd number is : " + num);
  } else {
    num++;
  }
}
```

Comment: `num` would end up as the value `1` forever(it isn't the issue of a browser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`num` would end up as the value `1` forever since when `num` is odd, it won't ever change.. to fix this, take out the `else`

```js
var num = 1
while (num < 26) {
  if (num % 2 !== 0) {
    console.log("The odd number is : " + num);
  } num++;
}
```